# How to solve "Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'."?

Tags: asp.net-core, migration

I am trying to creating new column in "Setting" table name "Description". But I am getting error like,

> Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16
>   An error occurred while accessing the IWebHost on class 'Program'. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Invalid column name 'Description'.
>   Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I had tried to add column in another table, it's working fine. What was the cause behind this specific table. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created migration according to that change and applied it to the database?

Comment: Yes, I had added migration but it's not working for setting table only.

Comment: What will happen if you add column with different name from description?

Comment: Already tried. Same error

Comment: can you update your code

Comment: Check you table in database, have `Description` be added into the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your response. I had solved issue by just move the sequence of Dependency Injection in startup file.

Also,I was trying to migrate data base in Program.cs which cause issue. So moved that code in Startup.cs file.

```
            #region Migration

        context.Database.Migrate();

        HttpContextExtension.HttpContextAccessor = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var settingService = serviceProvider.GetService<ISettingService>();
        WebHelper.ContentRootPath = settingService.GetSettingByKey(Services.Constants.ConstantValues.SettingContentBasePath);

        #endregion
```